# Translating fields per node

Tags: entities, i18n-l10n

I have a content type which the editors (who don't have an administrator role), needs to set the idioms that the field is translatable. For example, he can say the title and the body are transtalatable. What is the best way to do it programatically? I thinked about use hook_field_language_alter, but i'm not sure.